# How can I tell my NodeJS server which button was clicked in an HTTP form with two buttons?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, http

I am trying to make a NodeJS webapp that takes user input in a text box, then uses it for one of two functions (client-side) based on which button was clicked. Can I
1) call a different action based on which button was clicked
or
2) pass in body of the post something differentiating the two buttons

I've noticed that I get two different responses to console.log(req.body) with the below code when the different buttons are pressed.
When I click the submit button, I get
     "{ handle: 'blahblahblah', hadunkachud: '' }"
and when I click the fresh button I get "{ handle: 'blahblahblah', hingle: '' }"

However, I can't figure out a way to access the unique part of the response because trying to access the second array value of req.body gives me nothing

code below is in Jade

```
extends layout

block content
    h1= title
    form#formEnterHandle(name="enterhandle",method="post",action="/showid")
        input(type="text", placeholder="themirage", name="handle")
        button(name = "hadunkachud", type="submit") submit
        button(name = "hingle", type = "submit") fresh
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use inputs instead of buttons and you can pass values:

```
extends layout

block content
    h1= title
    form#formEnterHandle(name="enterhandle",method="post",action="/showid")
        input(type="text", placeholder="themirage", name="handle")
        input(name="submit", value = "hadunkachud", type="submit")
        input(name="submit", value= "hingle", type = "submit")
```

Now the posted `submit` value should equal whichever button you clicked.

Comment: Got an error when I tried running code:
"input is self closing and should not have content" (for the button names) but I solved it by adding value="fresh" within the input to get the buttons text to appear correctly

Comment: What if my other button is a delete button? How would I differentialte?

Comment: @codeinprogress I would have a delete button submit a separate form that sent a `DELETE` request not a `POST` - that should hit a separate Node controller if you set your routes up correctly.

Comment: @AlienWebguy In my form the update button is of type submit and the delete is of type button. I am using jquery click() event on delete button to call an ajax delete/post request to '/delete' url which calls the delete method on my controller. I was wondering if there was a way to do it directly through the form, so both buttons will be 'submit' but will either hit different actions or single action and the controller will know whether to update or delete.